# Make a Qmenu behave like Qaction in Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to make a Qmenu such as File be triggered just a Qaction in Pyqt5.

I'm writing an application that needs to have only a Qmenu such as File for example, behave like Qaction, that is can be triggered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the aboutToShow() signal of QMenu.  In your handler, call your QAction's trigger() slot.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToShow
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#trigger

Comment: Great!  Can you mark my response as 'answer' if it answered your question.